# How can I get live preview in the Hololens through a USB connection?

Tags: hololens

I'm trying to enable live previewing without going through Wifi to reduce latency. Is there a clear way to live preview through a USB connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect the HoloLens to your PC via a micro-USB cable.  Open a web browser and open http://127.0.0.1:10080, you should see the web portal for your holoLens.  If you are using the HoloLens App to connect you can use the same address when you are connected via USB.